# Python BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Whenever I try to run this code:

```
def CheckStock(url,model):

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    RawHTML = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    Page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(RawHTML.text, "lxml")
```

I keep getting:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.adidas.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)
```

The url I am using is:

```
'https://www.adidas.com/us/stan-smith-shoes/FZ3815.html?forceSelSize=FZ3815_630'
```

The model is: `'FZ3815'`

Comment: Sorry in the URL i am using their isn't supposed to be a space between the 1 and the 5.

Comment: I noticed that and corrected it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question it's best to choose a specific question title. Your current title _Python BeautifulSoup and Requests_ is rather generic and doesn't describe your problem well. Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve your question in that regard. Also, don't forget to accept (tick check-mark next to an answer) and up-vote an answer when it answers your question. In this way your question stops showing up as unanswered. – Refer to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

To get correct page, specify different `User-Agent`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.adidas.com/us/stan-smith-shoes/FZ3815.html?forceSelSize=FZ3815_630'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

RawHTML = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
Page = BeautifulSoup(RawHTML.text, "lxml")
print(Page)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="theme-adidas" data-reactroot="" lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"><head><title data-rh="true" id="meta-title">Stan Smith Tropical Print Sneakers | adidas US</title><meta charset="utf-8" data-rh="true" id="meta-charset"/><meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" data-rh="true" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" id="meta-http-ua-compatible"/><meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" data-rh="true" http-equiv="Content-Type" id="meta-http-content-type"/><meta content="

...and so on.
```

Comment: Okay, how do I specify the User-Agent to Google Chrome on MacBook Pro 2019? I still am getting the same issue

Comment: @VinnieMac Open Chrome (or Firefox) developer tools -> Network Tab and look what HTTP headers is client sending to server. Probably you need to specify more headers, for example `Accept-Language` etc.

Comment: I dont know how to add that in, I tired to use a modify header with a google chrome extension. However, im not sure how to about doing so. I realized with the code, it's my requests.get() that is making this happen. Not sure how to go over this issue.